# Auto Transfer of logs from server to server

Tags: php, ftp

I was wondering how to use php to do an auto transfer of log files weekly from one server to a cloud account.

I have all the passwords and what not, I am just confused on how to set this file up. As a site I am running stores log files, we are trying to "push" them weekly to our cloud storage.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What cloud provider? (EC2, Azure, rackspace, etc?)  Your options depend on the API for the storage service you are using

Comment: Oh, the cloud provider is rackspace..

Comment: see edit, added a great example some guys did with PHP + the RackSpace storage API.  Pretty sure that'll guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your platform (Windows, *Nix), you would just want to use some scheduling system to invoke the PHP job either directly or via a local web call.

cron would be your *Nix tool of choice
A scheduled task in windows would work there.

Outside of that, you'd just need to use PHP's file classes, specifically [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), and whatever code you'd need for your cloud provider.

*EDIT: examples for RackSpace api*

These guys have done basically exactly what you need.
http://clloud.com/tutorials-and-tips/uploading-files-to-rackspace-cloud-using-php-aka-mosso/

I would build an upload script from that knowledge that does what you want.  Then just use cron or scheduled task to invoke it on your schedule

Comment: Cool.. I guess I was more confused of really how to set this all up. I appreciate the patience and putting up with my somewhat lack of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you Taylor, I was just wondering though, I followed his tutorial, and it all works except I am supposed to fill in a "container" and I have no clue what this is lol.

Comment: I don't use Rackspace, so I'm not 100% of their implementation.  In most cloud storage spaces they provide a construct basically like a folder on a hard drive, and this is called a container.  I would log into your rackspace account and look around for options to manage or create containers.  Worse case, search their help for how to create a container.  Then you just take that name and use it in the script.